# Finding numeric values in varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

sorry if this is a duplicate, I wasn't able to find what I was looking for in the answered questions.

I'm looking to query for only records with a field formatted like this numbers (0-9), hyphen (-), number (0-9), hyphen (-), numbers (0-9). This is what I have tried:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LOC_NAME)) LIKE '[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]'
```

The result set I'm looking for would be 123456-123-1234.
I thought at first they may have spaces so I trimmed the field but still no results are showing with the **ABOVE** query. The **BELOW** query returns them, but with other results:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE LOC_NAME LIKE '%[0-9]-[0-9]%'
```

But I would get results like 1-2-3 Place...

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using ?

Comment: is the number of digits between each hyphen constant. This is a big question

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have decent regex functions, you might want to split by hyphens and validate each number separately. You need this regex pattern: [0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+

Comment: DhruvJoshi- I'm using SQL Server 2012
scsimon- Yes they should be constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LOC_NAME)) NOT LIKE '%[^-0-9]%'
```

This checks that the field has no non-hyphens or non-digits.

If you specifically want two hyphens, separated by digits, then:

```
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LOC_NAME)) NOT LIKE '%[^-0-9]%' AND
      LTRIM(RTRIM(LOC_NAME)) LIKE '[0-9]%-[0-9]%-[0-9]%' AND
      LTRIM(RTRIM(LOC_NAME)) NOT LIKE '%-%-%-%'
```

The second pattern requires at least two hyphens and a digit in all three parts of the name.  The third forbids three hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way

```
select *
from table_1
where isnumeric(replace(LOC_NAME, '-','')) = 1;
```

**Update** (2018-Jun-12)

After reading the comments of @EzLo, I realized that the OP may just need two hyphens (no more, no less), so I am updating my answer with the following demo code

```
create table #t (LOC_NAME varchar(100));
go

insert into #t (loc_name) 
values ('a12-b12-123'), ('123456-123-11'), ('123-123-123-123')
go

select *
from #t --table_1
where isnumeric(replace(LOC_NAME, '-','')) = 1
and len(loc_name)-len(replace(LOC_NAME, '-',''))=2
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: This will return incorrect match with more than 3 hyphens.

Comment: Sounds strange to me, @EzLo, can you give an example? To me, it does not matter how many hyphens you have as all hyphens will be removed by the [replace] function.

Comment: Oh, I guess, @EzLo you are referring to Gordon's answer. :-)

Comment: the OP wants to validate against a pattern with 3 hyphens, no more no less